# SOQL Query : Parent to Child Query result

Tags: apex, soql

This is my SOQL

```
SELECT ID,NAME,
 (SELECT ID,JUNCTION_TEXT__C FROM SPENDACCOUNT__C.CASE_SPEND_ACCOUNTS__R) 
FROM SPENDACCOUNT__C
```

SpendAccount__c is the Master.

Case_Spend_Account__c is the Child.

When I execute the following SOQL in Query Editor I am able to view the results (like shown below)

[image]

I was curious as to how I will be able to view the aggregated result (JUNCTION_TEXT__C coming from the child) and when I did the following anon apex I could not view the aggregated part at all.

My anon apex shown below.

[image]

Debug log output

[image]

What am I missing ?..can someone help ?

Comment: You do not have any SOQL aggregation in you code. Are you trying to use the Master-Detail Roll Up Summary functionality?

Answer (score 4):

The subquery will return a list of "Case_Spend_Account__c" records under each "SPENDACCOUNT__C" record. If any "SPENDACCOUNT__C" does not have child records, "CASE_SPEND_ACCOUNTS__R" will be an empty list. In order to use the child records, you need to iterate over the child list.

```
       for(SPENDACCOUNT__C parent:[SELECT ID,NAME,(SELECT ID,JUNCTION_TEXT__C FROM SPENDACCOUNT__C.CASE_SPEND_ACCOUNTS__R) FROM SPENDACCOUNT__C]){
            //Since subquery is returning a list, if you want to check if child list is empty.
            if(!parent.SPENDACCOUNT__C.CASE_SPEND_ACCOUNTS__R.isEmpty()){
                for(Case_Spend_Account__c child:parent.SPENDACCOUNT__C.CASE_SPEND_ACCOUNTS__R){
                    System.debug(child);
                }
            }else{
                System.debug('No Child');
            }
        }
```

Please check the link for details - https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: I think OP wants to know why the same query done in the QueryEditor versus anonymous apex delivers different display  results when comparing query editor output to system.debug output