# Trying to access a child object using a query but getting a compile error

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, compile-error

Here is my Trigger

```
trigger DailyTaskTrackersTrigger on Daily_Task_Tracker__c (before insert, before update,after insert,after update){

    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore){
        BusinessHours stdBusinessHours = [select id from businesshours where isDefault = true];
        for(Daily_Task_Tracker__c workObj: Trigger.new){
            if((workObj.Work_Start_Time__c != NULL) && (stdBusinessHours != NULL)){
                workObj.Target_Date_Time__c = BusinessHours.add(stdBusinessHours.Id,workObj.Work_Start_Time__c,long.valueOf(String.valueOf(workObj.Estimate_Time_To_Complete_Hrs__c  * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
            }
        }
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        list<User_Daily_Task_Tracker__c>UserDailyTaskTrc = new list<User_Daily_Task_Tracker__c>();
        for(Daily_Task_Tracker__c workObj:[SElECT ID,Name,(SELECT Name From User_Daily_Task_Tracker__r) FROM Daily_Task_Tracker__c WHERE ID IN: Trigger.new]){
            for(User_Daily_Task_Tracker__c uds: workObj.User_Daily_Task_Tracker__r){
                uds.name = workObj.Name;
                UserDailyTaskTrc.add(uds);

          }
        }
        update uds1;
    }
}
```

> Error: Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'User_Daily_Task_Tracker__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 25 column 44

Comment: you should try 'User_Daily_Task_Trackers__r' as well...note the 'S' added before '__r'.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about which line of code is causing the error and what you've tried to resolve this yourself.  Is there any reason you've included the commented out code?  Please at least make an effort to help us help you.

Comment: Also:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75792/soql-query-parent-to-child-query-result

Comment: Could you try adding Id field to the sub query

Comment: Dupe? [How to identify look up relations to an object in Salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/130748/2995)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to run the following in `Execute Anonymous`  to verify the verbatim relationship name to use in SOQL:

```
for(ChildRelationship relationship : SObjectType.Daily_Task_Tracker__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relationship.getChildSObject == User_Daily_Task_Tracker__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relationship.getRelationshipName());
```

Whatever the above output, use verbatim in your subquery. If it yields `Unicorns__r`, use:

```
(SELECT Id FROM Unicorns__r)
```

More likely it will yield `User_Daily_Task_Trackers__r`. If so, use:

```
(SELECT Id FROM User_Daily_Task_Tracker__c)
```

Usually it should be plural.